# GetTokenAsync returns 2 audiences in ASP.NET Core 2.1 using auth0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, auth0

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.1 and Auth0.

When I try to retrieve the acces_token to access my own API I use

```
string accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
```

The strange thing is when I paste the token on https://jwt.io/ it shows that an audience has been added. The thing is that two audiences are not allowed and so the token is not valid. The audience that is added ends with /userinfo

Can someone please explain why there are two audiences in my acces token?

I use the following code in ConfigureServices

```
// Add authentication services
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOpenIdConnect("Auth0", options =>
{
    // Set the authority to your Auth0 domain
    options.Authority = $"https://{Configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}";

    // Configure the Auth0 Client ID and Client Secret
    options.ClientId = Configuration["Auth0:ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Auth0:ClientSecret"];

    // Set response type to code
    options.ResponseType = "code";

    // Configure the scope
    options.Scope.Clear();
    options.Scope.Add("openid");

    // Set the callback path, so Auth0 will call back to http://localhost:5000/signin-auth0
    // Also ensure that you have added the URL as an Allowed Callback URL in your Auth0 dashboard
    options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-auth0");

    // Configure the Claims Issuer to be Auth0
    options.ClaimsIssuer = "Auth0";

    // Saves tokens to the AuthenticationProperties
    options.SaveTokens = true;

    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        // handle the logout redirection
        OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = (context) =>
        {
            var logoutUri = $"https://{Configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}/v2/logout?client_id={Configuration["Auth0:ClientId"]}";

            var postLogoutUri = context.Properties.RedirectUri;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(postLogoutUri))
            {
                if (postLogoutUri.StartsWith("/"))
                {
                    // transform to absolute
                    var request = context.Request;
                    postLogoutUri = request.Scheme + "://" + request.Host + request.PathBase + postLogoutUri;
                }
                logoutUri += $"&returnTo={ Uri.EscapeDataString(postLogoutUri)}";
            }

            context.Response.Redirect(logoutUri);
            context.HandleResponse();

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
        {
            context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("audience", "MY_OWN_AUDIENCE_URL");

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }    
    };
});
```

Comment: Have a look at `options.TokenValidationParameters` to set multiple audiences.

Comment: But the thing is that I don't want multiple audiences. I only need my own.

Comment: You need that other audience to retrieve the user’s userinfo though.

Comment: I think I get it. The audience that is added is to the auth0 management API? And that would mean that I need to configure multiple audiences?

Comment: Yeah, it’s added by Auth0 to authorize the client to access Auth0’s userinfo endpoint. And yeah, you should not invalidate a token that contains more audiences than you need. Just check for those that you require and ignore the rest.

Comment: Please **do not** edit your question to include the answer. The answer should be reflected below, not as part of your question.

Comment: @Brian You're not issuing the token so you don't have a say in it (unless there's an option at Auth0 to not include the userinfo audience).  If you want the token to validate you need to specify the valid audiences in token validation parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WORKING**

I got it working with the next code placed in ConfigureServices in the Startup class. In the List from Configuration I placed the audience from Auth0 userinfo API and my own API.

```
// Multiple audiences
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateAudience = true,
    ValidAudiences = Configuration.GetSection("Auth0:Audiences").Get<List<string>>(),
    ValidateLifetime = true
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone please explain why there are two audiences in my acces token?

The second audience is the userinfo endpoint. The [userinfo endpoint is part of the OpenID Connect protocol](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo); it exposes the end-user's profile information and is present because of the `openid` scope.

When Auth0 receives an authorization request, it checks the request's `audience` and `scope` parameters. If the `audience` is a custom API, and if the `scope` includes `openid`, then the `access_token` will include two audiences: one for your custom API, the other for the Auth0 userinfo endpoint.

Here is a supporting quote from https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/access-token

> When the audience is set to a custom API and the scope parameter includes the `openid` value, then the generated Access Token will be a JWT valid for both retrieving the user's profile and for accessing the custom API. The `aud` claim of this JWT will include two values: `YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN/userinfo` and your custom API's unique identifier.

Comment: I find it strange that Auth0 doesn't say anything about this in the ASP.NET Core 2.x tutorial.

Comment: Yes. That is unfortunate.