# How to resolve Auth0 Audience is invalid error

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, auth0, okta

In a Xamarin mobile/.Net app, after using Auth0 and successfully authenticating with the correct user name and password, we are trying to use the token to make an API call to our backend, but are we getting the following response saying that the token we are using is invalid because of the audience:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience 'https://webapi-dev...com, https://xyz.us.auth0.com/userinfo' is invalid"
```

(xyz being our tenant)
We know where the first audience comes from (the mobile client) and it is correct, but we have no idea where this value is coming from: "https://xyz.us.auth0.com/userinfo"
That value doesn't exist anywhere, anyone have any ideas?

[image: Screen shot of application output]

I tried to add that weird audience in the backend server and the mobile app [using this logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51799912/gettokenasync-returns-2-audiences-in-asp-net-core-2-1-using-auth0) but that didnt fix the issue

Comment: have you contacted auth0 support?  Are you sure this is not setup somewhere in your Auth0 config?  If I google the second subdomain it returns results related to the first one, so I assume they are actually related somehow.

Comment: Use the audience as defined in Applications > APIs. For example, mine is `https://dev-06bzs1cu.us.auth0.com/api/v2/`.